# Postman Get variable from a file

Tags: postman

I use Postman on a daily basis, and I need a 'token' that changes every 5 minutes. There is no way to get the token using PostMan.

I use an enviroment variable but this means that I have to change this variable every 5 minutes. This means multiple proceedings every time.

Is there a way to save the variable in a file? So I can set variables with my favorite text editor?

Comment: Q1: when your token is being geerated? on user authenticaton i.e login?